# How can I display lyrics of music playing in android

Tags: android, android-music-player

I have made a music player for android phones but I want to display lyrics when the music plays, Could somebody help me out who has an idea of how to do it.

Comment: Where are your lyrics coming from?

Comment: It is an offline music player, so I am gathering all the music files available inside phones storage. but I don't know how I should display lyrics when this music files are played. Do you is there any way to fetch lyrics from these files or any platform from where I can get the lyrics for such songs?